# Как в таблице динамически создать <tbody>

Tags: javascript, html

`<thead>`  создаётся `createTHead()`;
`<tfoot>`  создаётся `createTFoot()`;

Вопрос: как динамически создать тэг `<tbody>`?

Comment: это забавно, но для tbody нет специальной секции, и похоже даже специального интерфейса

Comment: Вот я и забавляюсь уже второй день. Перелопатил документацию и ничего не нашел

Comment: придется написать свою функцию

Comment: не, не все так плохо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В спецификации `HTML4` метод для создания `TBody` отсутствует. Проясняться это может тем, что `THead` и `TFoot` у таблицы должны быть в единственном экземпляре, и при повторном вызове функций *createTHead*, *createTFoot*, будет возвращен существующий экземпляр. В то время как `TBody` может быть несколько. Поэтому для него не нужен особый метод и можно было использовать обычный [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement)

```
table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
```

Но в [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element), судя по всему, решили передумать и добавили соответствующий метод

[createTBody()](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#dom-table-createtbody)

Который создает элемент и добавляет его в конец таблицы.

Судя по [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement#Browser_compatibility) данный метод поддерживается всеми основными браузерами.

Comment: Весьма благодарен!